# R Scatter Plot Matrix

Tags: r, matrix, scatter-plot

I need some piece of advice regarding scatter plot matrices in R. I know already everything about creating one by using the `pairs` functions, however, this doesn't provide me with what I truly need.

I made a correlation analysis between X, and 8 different Y properties. While I'm not interested about the correlation between all properties of Y, hence the `pairs` function doesn't work for me.

Rather, I won't to have a matrix scatter plot containing 8 scatters (e.g. 4x2), each of the containing categorical variables.

For example, let's assume we have an independent variable X which we correlate with Y1, Y2, Y3....Y8. However, we don't wanna correlate neither of the Yn variables, because these are all dependent. Unfortunately, I cannot provide some example figures.

Any advice?

Comment: A reproducible example is welcome.

Comment: @Pascal, updates the description. Hope this time it will be clearer.

Comment: I was speaking about data.

Answer (score 1):

`ggpairs` from `GGally` package is doing a pretty nice job..

[a blog article with examples](https://tgmstat.wordpress.com/2013/11/13/plot-matrix-with-the-r-package-ggally/)